# How to specify different option values on module with multiple instances, in a stream defined in spring-xd?

Tags: spring-xd

For example, I'd like to define a stream in Spring-XD as, 'source1 | sink1'
and the 'source1' module has a option: 'option1'.

What I like to do is to configure 'source1' to have multiple instances (this is doable in Spring-XD), and at the same time,  I like to let each instance of 'source1' to have different value on 'option1'.

Is it possible with currently-available DSL design in Spring-xd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't currently do that but you can use [named channels](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#named-channels)...

```
stream create --name foo --definition "source1 --option=x > queue:xx"
stream create --name bar --definition "source1 --option=y > queue:xx"
stream create --name baz --definition "queue:xx > sink1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Gary. The 'named channel' approach definitely works! BTW, do you think it will be good for Spring XD to support heterogeneous option values for module instances, without introducing the named channels?

Comment: If you open a [new feature JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD) the team will consider it. Personally, I think the stream definition will get rather complicated; it will also require some coupling of the stream definition (where the options are set) and the deployment manifest (where the module counts are set), so it could be tricky. By the way, there is no physical difference between named and anonymous channels; named channels were implemented for use cases like this; they have no additional runtime overhead.

Comment: Glad to hear that named channel introduces no extra runtime overhead than anonymous channel. The named channel approach may suffice for my case, thanks for your option on the possible disadvantage in extra coupling and complication incurred from extending stream definition to support _this_ feature.